# Logout redirect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am having trouble logging a user out and clearing the sessions for the user. I keep getting the following error in my rails server terminal window:

```
Started DELETE "/logout" for ::1 at 2014-12-01 17:17:47 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant SessoinsController):
```

Here is the controller for sessions:

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    # SESSIONS ARE NOT AN ACTIVE RECORD MODEL

    def new
    end

    def create
      user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        log_in user
        redirect_to user
      else
        # flash.now is used so when going to homepage the danger
        # message is not there anymore
        # designed for displaying flash on rendered pages
        flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid email/password combination"
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    # logs out the current user, check session_helper for details
    def destroy
      log_out
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "You have successfully logged out."
    end

  end
```

Here is the sessions helper:
     module SessionsHelper

```
  # logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # returns the current logged-in user (if any)
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # logs out the current user
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

Here are my routes.

```
get 'users/new'
# These routes are from the static_pages controller
root               'static_pages#home'
get 'help'      => 'static_pages#help'
get 'about'     => 'static_pages#about'
get 'contact'   => 'static_pages#contact'
get 'signup'    => 'users#new'
get 'login'     => 'sessions#new'
post 'login'    => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout' => 'sessoins#destroy'
resources :users
```

Can someone please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `uninitialized constant SessoinsController`?  It's looking for `SessoinsController` but your controller class is `SessionsController`.  Lets see your routes

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you for pointing that out for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your routes

```
logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         sessoins#destroy
```

**sessions** is spelled wrong

Just make sure this line is correct:

```
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```